# What's difference between Assets.xcassets and images.xcassets?

Tags: ios, xcode, image, project

When I new a xcode project, there was a image folder by defalut, I wanna to know that is there any difference between them? Is Assets.xcassets newer?

Answer (score 5):

**What is Asset?**

Asset catalogs to organize and manage the different asset types and image resolutions used by your app’s user interface.

You can have **multiple asset catalogs** in your project and within each catalog, multiple sets of assets. In addition, you can organize sets into folders.The common types of sets you can add to a catalog are **image, data, and texture sets**.

**Now you understand that image asset is one of the asset catalog.**

It will automatically created by Xcode when creating new projects.

**Common use of Asset catalog :**

> In particular, use asset catalogs to manage images that are required
> to launch your app on a device and submit your app to the App Store.

As above statements from apple there are multiple asset types are available.You can create catalog for each type if you want.

**[Asset types](http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev70f9ac19b)**

[image]

You can get more info from [help.apple.com](http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev10510b1f7)

Comment: well, then I just have one small question, which version of xcode has Assets.xcassets first time.

Answer (score 2):

Not really sure but I think since Xcode 7 you have this new Assets.xcassets catalog to store several types of resources, not just images as you can have sounds, images, fonts and movies in your project.